# Limitar o número de usos de uma função

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou criando um mini rpg em javascript e estou com uma dúvida na parte da criação de personagens, gostaria de saber como limitar o número de usos de uma função.

```
  var personagem = new Object;

  personagem.carisma = 1;
  personagem.força = 1;
  personagem.inteligencia = 1;

  window.onload = init;
  function init () {
    var button1 = document.getElementById('char');
    var button2 = document.getElementById('for');
    var button3 = document.getElementById('int');
    button1.onclick = buttonClickCarisma;
    button2.onclick = buttonClickForce;
    button3.onclick = buttonClickInt;
  }

  function buttonClickCarisma () {
    if( personagem.carisma < 3 ) {
      personagem.carisma = personagem.carisma + 1;
      console.log(personagem.carisma);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Seu carisma está no máximo!');
    }
  }

  function buttonClickForce () {
    if( personagem.força < 3 ) {
      personagem.força = personagem.força + 1;
      console.log(personagem.força);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Sua força está no máximo!');
    }
  }

  function buttonClickInt () {
    if( personagem.inteligencia < 3 ) {
      personagem.inteligencia = personagem.inteligencia + 1;
      console.log(personagem.inteligencia);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Sua inteligência está no máximo!');
    }
  }
```

Esse pedaço de código demonstra a criação de personagens, onde eu gostaria de limitar o número de uso das funções buttonClickCarisma, buttonClickForce e buttonClickInt para apenas 3 usos ( se eu usar uma 3 vezes não posso qualquer outra ), algo semelhante a criação de personagens em jogos da saga Fallout. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: poderia usar uma variável para contar as vezes que a função foi utilizada, e cada vez que executa a função incrementar ou decrementar essa variável!

Comment: Melhor é mesmo limitar os valores máximos de cada caracteristica do jogador, que é o que o código já faz. Limitar a quantidade de vezes que uma função executa é algo que não se costuma ver em código pois regra geral é a forma errada de abordar o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer seria limitar a quantidade de pontos de atributos que a pessoa pode usar, observe a variável `limiteAtributos` no código abaixo:

```
var personagem = new Object;

personagem.carisma = 1;
personagem.força = 1;
personagem.inteligencia = 1;
var limiteAtributos = 3;

window.onload = init;
function init () {
    var button1 = document.getElementById('char');
    var button2 = document.getElementById('for');
    var button3 = document.getElementById('int');
    button1.onclick = buttonClickCarisma;
    button2.onclick = buttonClickForce;
    button3.onclick = buttonClickInt;
}

function buttonClickCarisma () {
    if(limiteAtributos > 0){
        if( personagem.carisma < 3 ) {
            personagem.carisma = personagem.carisma + 1;
            limiteAtributos = limiteAtributos - 1;
            console.log(personagem.carisma);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Seu carisma está no máximo!');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Todos os atributos já foram usados');
    }
}

function buttonClickForce () {
    if(limiteAtributos > 0){
        if( personagem.força < 3 ) {
            personagem.força = personagem.força + 1;
            limiteAtributos = limiteAtributos - 1;
            console.log(personagem.força);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Sua força está no máximo!');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Todos os atributos já foram usados');
    }
}

function buttonClickInt () {
    if(limiteAtributos > 0){
        if( personagem.inteligencia < 3 ) {
            personagem.inteligencia = personagem.inteligencia + 1;
            limiteAtributos = limiteAtributos - 1;
            console.log(personagem.inteligencia);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Sua inteligência está no máximo!');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Todos os atributos já foram usados');
    }
}
```

Comment: Não tinha pensado em primeiro verificar e depois retirar do valor da variável, finalmente consegui resolver, obrigado e abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Vou criar um exemplo:

```js
let qtdVezes = 0;

function usarFunc () {
  if(qtdVezes >= 5){
      alert('Você não pode mais usar essa função!');
      return false;
  }
  
  qtdVezes++;
  console.log('Você está usando a função pela ' + qtdVezes + ' vez');
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="usarFunc()">Apertar</button>
```

Só irá funcionar novamente se a pessoa atualizar a página.

Comment: Caso utilize banco de dados também poderia gravar essa quantidade no banco e checar ao fazer a função, ai se atualiza-se a página iria continuar a quantidade.

Comment: Ao modificar seu código pra se encaixar ao jogo ele parava de contar os pontos atribuídos, mas mesmo assim consegui resolver o problema com base no seu código, obrigado e abraço!